# bash script to check connectivity in multiple servers (avoid ECDSA key are you sure you want....)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting

not an linux expert but I´m trying to see a way of using a bash script to check connectivity tu multiple servers and avoid any human intervention.

I have something like this, so that I can connect to a host, execute hostname and put that info in a log

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in $(cat server.txt)
do
        ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=3 "$host" "hostname"
done > servers.log
```

Is this possible to execute and avoid the

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is a3:eb:a8:4d:90:1d:ae:83:bc:7b:a9:47:69:67:67:7f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
 ?
```

or just to force toy say YES?

thank you

Comment: Use Google with `ssh disable "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"`.

Comment: Hello - And ask for "practical example of expect" too.

Answer (score 3):

To suppress this warning in `ssh` command use:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@host
```

Also use `while read` loop instead of `for` loop like this:

```
while read -r host; do
    ssh -tt -oBatchMode=yes -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "user@$host"
done < server.txt > servers.log
```

Comment: And you can still have your log - `done < server.txt  > servers.log`

Comment: Thanks Paul, I missed it.

Comment: Im getting: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: ok try: `ssh -tt -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "user@$host"`

Comment: I tried with original script that I posted with o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" and it worked, but some servers is asking for password. I would like to do "CTRL C" to continue with the rest of the list of servers or to interrupt somehow that prompt for password and continue. Is this possible?